# HttpClient PostAsync equivalent in JQuery with FormURLEncodedContent instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, owin

I wrote a JQuery script to do a user login POST (tried to do what I have done with C# in the additional information section, see below).

After firing a POST with the JQuery code from my html page, I found the following problems:

**1 -** I debugged into the server side code, and I know that the POST is received by the server (in ***ValidateClientAuthentication()*** function, but not in ***GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()*** function).

**2 -** Also, on the server side, I could not find any sign of the ***username*** and ***password***, that should have been posted with ***postdata***. Whereas, with the ***user-side C# code***, when I debugged into the ***server-side C# code***, I could see those values in the ***context*** variable. I think, this is the whole source of problems.

**3 -** The JQuery code calls **function getFail**().

**? -** I would like to know, what is this ***JQuery code*** doing differently than the ***C# user side code*** below, and how do I fix it, so they do the same job?

(**My guess:** is that ***JSON.stringify*** and ***FormURLEncodedContent*** do something different)

**JQuery/Javascript code:**

```
function logIn() {
var postdata = JSON.stringify(
{
    "username": document.getElementById("username").value,
    "password": document.getElementById("password").value
});

try {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Token",
        cache: false,
        data: postdata,
        dataType: "json",
        success: getSuccess,
        error: getFail
    });
} catch (e) {
    alert('Error in logIn');
    alert(e);
}
function getSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert('getSuccess in logIn');
    alert(data.Response);
};
function getFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('getFail in logIn');
    alert(jqXHR.status); // prints 0
    alert(textStatus); // prints error
    alert(errorThrown); // prints empty
};
```

};

**Server-side handling POST (C#):**

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(
        OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // after this line, GrantResourceOwnerCredentials should be called, but it is not.
        await Task.FromResult(context.Validated());
    }


public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(
        OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var manager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError(
                "invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }

        // Add claims associated with this user to the ClaimsIdentity object:
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        foreach (var userClaim in user.Claims)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(userClaim.ClaimType, userClaim.ClaimValue));
        }

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
```

***Additional information:*** In a C# client-side test application for my C# Owin web server, I have the following code to do the POST (works correctly):
**User-side POST (C#):**

```
//...
HttpResponseMessage response;
var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "grant_type", "password"), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "username", userName ), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string> ( "password", password )
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var tokenEndpoint = new Uri(new Uri(_hostUri), "Token"); //_hostUri = http://localhost:8080/Token
    response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, content);
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `dataType` controls what jQuery expects the *returned* data to be, not what `data` is. To set the content type of the *request* data (`data`), you use `contentType: "json"` instead. (More in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).)

var postdata = JSON.stringify(
{
    "username": document.getElementById("username").value,
    "password": document.getElementById("password").value
});

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/Token",
    cache: false,
    data: postdata,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "json",  // <=== Added
    success: getSuccess,
    error: getFail
});
```

If you weren't trying to *send* JSON, but instead wanted to send the usual URI-encoded form data, you wouldn't use `JSON.stringify` at all and would just give the object to jQuery's `ajax` directly; jQuery will then create the URI-encoded form.

```
try {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/Token",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            "username": document.getElementById("username").value,
            "password": document.getElementById("password").value
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: getSuccess,
        error: getFail
    });
    // ...
```

Comment: context.Validated() in ValidateClientAuthentication, still does not pass? Should I ask a new question for that?
Actually, context.Validated set haserror to false, and isValidated to true now. But for some reason, it does not go to GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()

Comment: @Snowman: Did you remember to add a third data parameter for grant_type=password?

Comment: @DaveWard I don't know what you mean. Should I add, in the JQuery, data {
"grant_type": "password",
...
}?

Comment: @DaveWard I added "grant_type": "password" to my data in JQuery, and now I get into the GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() on the server, thank you. (You could edit it into T.J. Crowder's answer, or as a separate answer too, so I can upvote it :) )

Comment: @Snowman: Great. Glad that helped. I added an answer with that extra info and a bit more. I'll let T.J. update his if he thinks any of it would be worth adding. I don't like to mess with other peoples' answers.

Answer (score 1):

To add to T.J.'s answer just a bit, another reason that sending JSON to the `/token` endpoint didn't work is simply that it does not support JSON.

Even if you set `$.ajax's` contentType option to `application/json`, like you would to send JSON data to MVC or Web API, `/token` won't accept that payload. It only supports form URLencoded pairs (e.g. username=dave&password=hunter2). `$.ajax` does that encoding for you automatically if you pass an object to its `data` option, like your `postdata` variable if it hadn't been JSON stringified.

Also, you must remember to include the `grant_type=password` parameter along with your request (as your `PostAsync()` code does). The `/token` endpoint will respond with an "invalid grant type" error otherwise, even if the username and password are actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery's $.param to urlencode the data when sending the form data . AngularJs' $http method currently does not do this.

Like

```
var loginData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: $scope.loginForm.email,
            password: $scope.loginForm.password
        };

        $auth.submitLogin($.param(loginData))
          .then(function (resp) {
              alert("Login Success"); // handle success response
          })
          .catch(function (resp) {
              alert("Login Failed");  // handle error response
          });
```

Since angularjs  1.4 this is pretty trivial with the $httpParamSerializerJQLike:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: baseUrl,
      data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
        "user":{
          "email":"wahxxx@gmail.com",
          "password":"123456"
        }
      }),
      headers:
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
})
```